# Facebook API - Invalid signed request. (Invalid signature.)

Tags: asp.net, api, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm tryng to use Facebook authentication at http://landlordscores.co.uk/account/login.aspx but after logging in with facebook, the callback page displays "Invalid signed request. (Invalid signature.) ". The app ID and secret are correct and no other information seems to be logged. This happens every time I try to log in with facebook.

**Edit:**
To make the call, I'm using pretty much the exact code as the sample.
In the markup:

```
<iframe src="<%= this.RegistrationUrl %>"
                        scrolling="auto"
                        frameborder="no"
                        style="border:none"
                        allowTransparency="true"
                        width="100%"
                        height="500">
                  </iframe>
```

In the code-behind:

```
public string RegistrationUrl {
    get
        {
    var url = string.Format(
    "http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&fields={2}",
    FacebookApplication.Current.AppId,
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode(AppBLL.GetAbsoluteURL("~/Account/fbregcallback.aspx")),
    HttpUtility.UrlEncode("[{\"name\":\"name\"},{\"name\":\"email\"},{\"name\":\"location\"},{\"name\":\"password\",\"view\":\"not_prefilled\"},{\"name\":\"captcha\"}]"));            this.RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl = this.Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    this.hdnPassLength.Value = Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength.ToString();
                            HttpUtility.UrlEncode("[{\"name\":\"name\"},{\"name\":\"email\"},{\"name\":\"location\"},{\"name\":\"password\",\"view\":\"not_prefilled\"},{\"name\":\"captcha\"}]"));       
    this.hdnPassLength.Value = Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to make the call?

Comment: Thanks, I've added a code sample

Comment: When you say you are using sample code...where are you getting your sample?  You do not appear to be using the Facebook C# SDK (your question has this SDK tagged), and your code does not use the Javascript SDK / Registration plugin recommended by Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: @Echilon Have you looked at Request.Params["signed_request"] to see if it's returning anything at all? 

also what version of the C# SDK are you using?

Comment: Have you tried using the sample code on this page:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ ?  If you click Register on the example on that page, you'll get an echo response that may help debug your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you have done this already but I have had the same issue and all I had to do was add my app ID and secret to the web.config.

In the web.config file, my issue was on this line. Ensuring these are populated and accurate should solve the issue.

```
<facebookSettings appId="xxxxxxxx"  appSecret="xxxxxxx"  cookieSupport="true" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find this has something to do with cookies.

I was playing around with the different sample web sites that have in the sdk. I cleared my cookies and then I stopped getting that error.

Answer (score -2):

You must check your app settings on facebook. Take care about the URLs and other settings.

Comment: Pretty lame answer to cash in on the bounty. Checking the settings were correct was the first thing I tried before posting.